# Check what all methods were called when I called a method when unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing

I am trying to make some test classes to test whether caching in my project works correctly. The easiest way to do so would be something like this:

```
MyCache cache = new MyCache(new MyDataSource());
MyResult = cache.load(somepath); //This calls some method MyDataSource.getData which is expensive
//Here the thing I need comes
Magic.cleanStackTrace(); //Prepare clean buffer for all called methods
//Call the cache load again
cache.load(somepath);
//Check if expensive MyDataSource.getData has been called
List<Method> methodsCalled = Magic.getAllFunctionsCalledAfterClean(); //Again, fictional finction
//Loop through lost and check if MyDataSource.getData is there or not
```

This would allow me to ensure that everything is cached as well as that the cache is being deleted when it should. I can also imagine other tests with different purpose - such as security, cleanup from debug methods and so on.

Is this possible? In this case, I think there's no shame in super dirty solution as it's just testing and everything is allowed.

Comment: Have you tried mocking `MyDataSource.getData()` to increment a counter and check the value of the counter??

Comment: @assylias I don't want to edit the `getData` function. Actually, that's what I did now, but I'm looking for more automated and clean approach.

Comment: I'm not suggest to edit it but to mock it with a mocking framework. Alternatively you could use a `new MyCache(new CountingDatasource());` and pass a "fake" datasource to your cache.

Comment: Ah  I see, that's a good idea for many cases. Unfortunatelly, the situation in my program is a little different. There are some hardcoded static functions and the system is kinda complex. As such, making a whole fake data loading system would be too much work.

Comment: [Powermock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) allows you to mock static methods and access private state of classes under test through bytecode instrumentation and reflection. You can pretty much do anything with that framework.